# Storing ArrayList and HashMap using java.util.properties

Tags: java, properties, arraylist, hashmap, configuration-files

How can I store an `ArrayList` and/or a `HashMap` variable using `java.util.properties`? If it's not possible what other class can I use to store application configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to serialize your collections into Strings, I *highly* recommend [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). It uses reflection to serialize a class into XML. There is documentation if the default behavior doesn't work for the class you want to serialize, but the following has worked for me every time so far:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
String xml = xstream.toXML(myObject);
MyClass deserializedObject = (MyClass)xstream.fromXML(xml);
assert deserializedObject.equals(myObject);
```

Comment: This is very good but it doesn't have any method to check & validate input file and just throws some bad exceptions!

Comment: @Snigger the exceptions are the validation, if the input file isn't valid than an exception is thrown while reading it.

Answer (score 2):

So... if "*don't do that*" doesn't work for you, then you need to encode the data somehow.  One common technique is to prepend some string to the name of each element.  For example if I have a map MyMap containing a->1, b->2, c->3, I might store in the properties file:

```
MyMap.a=1
MyMap.b=2
MyMap.c=3
```

For lists, you can do the same, just mapping indices to values.  So if MyList contains {a,b,c}

```
MyList.0=a
MyList.1=b
MyList.2=c
```

This is a hack, and everything everyone else said is true.  But sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: and how can i understand how many items are in the list to retrieve?

Comment: Either store that as a separate property, or just increment until you get nothing back.  Consider using an ArrayList instead of an array, so you don't care.

Answer (score 1):

`Properties` is basically `Map<String, String>` meaning both key and value must be String objects.  If you want more advanced configuration, you could go with Spring.  Its an excellent framework and I use it in every project.  Spring config files are extremely flexible.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Properties is only intended to be used with String keys and values. It does inherit the put() and putAll() methods from Hashtable, but it's rarely a good idea to use those to "cheat". Have you considered just storing your configuration information in a HashMap rather than a Properties object? You would have to customize the serialization a bit, but you're going to have to do that in any case as you can't take advantage of the default loading functionality of the Properties class.

Answer (score 1):

Storing a `HashMap` would be easy, since each key and value in the Map can be represented by a corresponding key and value in the `Properties` object (see the `setProperty` method in `Properties`.

For the `ArrayList` you could do something similar, the keys would be the indexes and the values the items in the corresponding indexes.

In both cases, remember that a properties file only stores strings, so you'd have to devise a way to represent the keys and values in your objects as strings.